# Getting SIGBUS after mmap for Huge Pages, even though HugePages_Free is positive

Tags: c++, c, linux, huge-pages

I am using `mmap` to allocate huge pages. This works fine, but sometimes I get near the limit of available huge pages and I get SIGBUS faults when I access the memory. But I don't understand why `mmap` succeeeded in the first place if there wasn't any memory, and I don't understand why `/proc/meminfo` seems to show that there is enough memory?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know how many huge pages are available, you need to do

```
grep Huge /proc/meminfo
```

and then subtract

```
availablePages = HugePages_Free - HugePages_Rsvd
```

That is because "Free" doesn't actually mean free. It just means that the memory has not been touched yet. If `availablePages` is 0, then you can't allocate any more Huge Pages successfully.  So chances are, you *have run out of memory*, but you got confused by the horrible output of `/proc/meminfo`.

However, `mmap` won't fail! ... so read the next paragraph too.

There is an unfortunate flaw in using `mmap` to allocate Huge Pages with the `MAP_NORESERVE` flag turned on. This means don't reserve swap space. However, `mmap` will *succeed* in "allocating" huge page memory even if the system can't 
handle it. In order to test whether `mmap` succeeding in physically allocating
the memory and having it available immediately is to make a call to [mincore()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mincore.2.html) to evaluate if every page was successfully allocated. I did it something like this:

```
  ptr = mmap( ... );
  ...

  uint32_t inMemoryPages = 0;
  for(int j=0;j<numDesiredPages;j++)
  {
       uint8_t flag;
       int s = mincore((uint8_t*)ptr + j * HugePageSize(), 1,&flag);
       // flag is 1 if the page was successfully allocated and in memory
       inMemoryPages += flag;
  }
  if (numDesiredPages != inMemoryPages)
  {
      std::stringstream ss;
      ss << "Unable to fulfill huge page allocation request."
         << " numDesiredPages:" << numDesiredPages
         << " successfulPages:" << inMemoryPages;
      throw std::runtime_error(ss.str());

  }
```

Otherwise, your `mmap` call can succeed and then you get `SIGBUS` later when you find out you didn't actually have enough huge page memory.